# MS Calendar REST API (create event)

Tags: api, rest, calendar, outlook

i am getting list of events/items from our company sharepoint/office365 calendar (according to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn605896(v=office.15).aspx#sectionSection5). It works fine, but now i want to create new event/item from my webapp. I am not able to find desired REST url (+parameters) to achieve this.

Thank you for any hint.

Answer (score 0):

I Solved the problem by:

making POST request to :

```
POST https://outlook.office365.com/ews/odata/Me/Calendar/Events
```

and send data in `JSON` format in the body of request :

```
{"Subject": "' . $subject . '",.....}
```